# How to set a java file for an included layout?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am including a layout in another like this:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I want to create a java file with onCreate method that would fire when the layout is included anywhere.

I am new to android so I might be trying to do the wrong thing.

Comment: You can't call a method when the layout in included but you can execute code when the included layout is inflated by using a custom view in the included layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be kind of difficult, but, like @emanuel-moecklin mentioned, you can wrap your `_home.xml` layout with a custom view, and then you could do add some code in the `onAttachedWindow`, `onMeasure`, `onLayout` or `onDraw` methods, check out [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDJXT.png) if you want to see more about the <strike>custom</strike> View lifecycle.

---

This would be your **CustomView.java**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomViewTAG_";

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Log.d(TAG, "This will get called everytime your CustomView gets attached");
    }
}
```

And something like this would be your **_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.CustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.example.CustomView>

    <!-- Your normal views -->

</FrameLayout>
```